# R- boolean: for-loop (vector in vector)

Tags: r, for-loop, boolean

I found this code from  one of the answers from other posting:
[R - Handling multiple values as one string in a single variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997086/r-handling-multiple-values-as-one-string-in-a-single-variable/29998064#comment107737705_29998064)

The code is very very useful, but I'm having hard time to understand boolean with for-loop.

```
# Data
text = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5")
lang = c("fr", "en", "fr,en", "sp,fr", "sp,fr,en")
d = data.frame(text, lang, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get a vector of the languages that exist
languages <- unique(unlist(strsplit(d$lang, ",")))

# Create a new column for each language
for (language in languages) d[[language]] <- grepl(language, d$lang)

# An example bar-plot
barplot(colSums(d[, -c(1, 2)]))
```

My question is about `for (language in languages) d[[language]] <- grepl(language, d$lang)`, which creating new columns for each language.

- **Question #1**: How does `for(**vector** in **vector**)` work? Does it create number of new columns(language) based on length of pattern(languages)?

  ```
    for(language in languages)
  ```

  I only used "for()" with numeric,

  ```
    for ( i in (1:n))
  ```

  and wonder how for(vector in vector) can be utilized.
- **Question #2**: this is MORE confusing that how can we use un-created language columns as pattern for prepl()?

  ```
    grepl(language, d$lang)
  ```

  because language columns are not created yet, but which used as a pattern for function grepl() to fill up empty language columns...

I need help to understand that specific line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do a `print` statement

```
for(language in languages) print(language)
#[1] "fr"
#[1] "en"
#[1] "sp"
```

it is returning each element in 'languages'

In each loop, it checks whether the substring is present in that 'lang' and creates a TRUE/FALSE logical vector from `grepl`, which is assigned (`<-`) as new column of the same name passed as `pattern`

```
for (language in languages) d[[language]] <- grepl(language, d$lang)
```

---

Consider the `mtcars` dataset

```
 data(mtcars)
```

If we want to create a new column

```
var1 <- "newvar"
mtcars[[var1]] <- 10
head(mtcars, 2)
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newvar
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     10
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     10
```

It creates the column 'newvar' ie. the value stored in the object, similar to the value passed i.e. 'fr', 'en', 'sp' in `for` loop

Comment: so language is created exactly as same as languages from  for (language in languages); then it sent to grepl() ; and then true/false are stored at d[[language]] ? Could you explain more about d[[language]] please?  when print this > print(d[[language]]) [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

Comment: @rocknRrr i added some description to the solution.  Once you assign the output and print that column, it gives the values of that column.  Here, the `grepl` returns logical output